# Proper handling text that was sent via JSON when returning html string and inserting it into tittle attribute

Tags: javascript, json, string, datatable, datatables

i have the following text (with new lines).

```
"☢☢☢☢2222def l2 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./  1 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./  2 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./def l2 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./  1 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./  2 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./"

122434 *()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./def l2 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./  1 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./  2 ❤ ☀ ☆ ☂ ☻ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € → ~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]\\|:;\"'<>?,./"
```

I use datatbles.js and there when populating cells i have a function that returns an html string

```
return '<span title="TEXT"></span>'
```

When i do this

```
return '<span title="'+text+'"></span>'
```

Or this

```
return '<span title="'+JSON.stringify(text)+'"></span>'
```

It breaks my returned element.

How could I approach inserting the text above with new lines etc. to the `title` attribute so it would work properly?

Thank you!

Comment: How does it 'break'? Does the ' character break it?

Comment: There are things like single and double quotes, square, curly, and angle brackets, and other such symbols and punctuation that can be interpreted as HTML markers instead of plain text. You will need to escape those characters according to [this spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references).

Comment: @Abion47 Thanks, it helped!

Answer (score -1):

If you do string concatenation you have to worry about all the details of encoding in HTML. Instead of passing HTML strings around, create DOM elements with JavaScript functions:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerText = text;
return span;
```

The caller should then use `appendChild()` to append this element where it's needed, rather than assigning it to `innerHTML`.

Comment: That would just end up in columns containing the text `[object HTMLSpanElement]`

Comment: You don't put the return value in `innerHTML`, you use `appendChild` to append it as a DOM element.

Comment: I understand your point but DataTables expect a string (treats values from the render callback as strings) ...You could use `return span.outerHTML` but that seem to ruin markup within data / text (i.e if text is `<p>something</p>`)